# having issue in extracting an element from xml

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have a xml like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <InsertReceipts> 
<receipts xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:string> 
    <![CDATA[ test]]>
     </a:string>
    </receipts> 
    </InsertReceipts>
```

I want to extract element a:string from this xml,but can't figure out to do this?

as i use  `XmlElement foo = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:string");`

it gives a parsing error

Feedback and help appreciated

Comment: sorry guys..got to early into asking this question ..figured out the solution.

Following trick will do the required work:
 

     XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("a","http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");
              //  XmlNode book = doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:string",nsmgr);
                XmlElement foo = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:string",nsmgr);

Idea is to use namespacemanager class to set the prefix on nodes.